# LaTeXiT indents first line

Tags: equations, latexit

I am fairly new to LaTeX and I am currently using it to insert formatted equations into Microsoft Word (Office 365 version on Mac). However, for some reason in indents the first line of a multi line equation. Is there anyway to remove this indent or does LaTeXiT assume that you only operate with one equation at a time?
[image]

Comment: Try using \noindent.

Comment: @JairoAraujo unfortunately this has the same issue

Comment: Sorry. As I'm a Linux user, I cannot test your example

Comment: this is not a multiline math display, you are marking up a two line _text_ paragraph hence the indent of the first line, which happens to have two separate inline math expressions. a two line display would be something like `\begin{align}f(x}&=0\\f(y)=1\end{align}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not familiar with that program, but I read `Align` in your screenshot. Try to click on `Align`, write

```
f(x)&=0\\
f(y)&=1
```

in the code section, and compile.

On the other hand,

```
\noindent$f(x)=0$
\\
$f(y)=1$
```

in `Text` mode should do what you want (as long it behaves as I expect).

---

*An answer Ryan Schaefer's question in the comment section below:* Elementary, `align` [sic!] is a very common and useful *environment* for math and very useful in `LaTeX` (I guess that is the reason why it it is in most left/first position), secondly, I have read https://chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php and by the functionality of the sw this is what I would expect/design as a sw engineer with some knowledge on `LaTeX`. I assume that the application basically compiles a LaTeX-document and returns a bitmap or vector graphic. David Carlisle's comment should work for the same reasons.

I might add that switching from Word to LaTeX might be beneficially if allowed possible, see [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner). Also using that image generated by LaTeXiT might give you font inconsistencies.

Comment: +1 (especially for not having the program) :)

Comment: Can I ask what led to your conclusion on the distinction between `Text` and `Align`

Comment: @RyanSchaefer See edit.